# Error[E0463]: can't find crate for std... how to compile Rust x32 in a x64 Windows machine?

Tags: windows, rust, cross-compiling, rust-cargo

I'm on Windows 10 x64. I have Visual Studio 2019 installed, which allows me to compile C and C++ for both x32 and x64 without problems.

Now, for Rust, I have the `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` toolchain installed through rustup, which allows me to compile x64 binaries just fine.

In an attempt to compile Rust x32, I installed the `stable-i686-pc-windows-msvc`, but when I run `cargo test --target i686-pc-windows-msvc`, it gives me `error[E0463]: can't find crate for std`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: what crate cant find?

Comment: Have you also installed the MSVC C/C++ build tools for your target? They need to be installed separately (Usually via the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer).

Comment: @Netwave My own crate.

Comment: @Locke Yes, [it's installed](https://i.imgur.com/8h1l0VB.png).

Comment: "I installed the stable-i686-pc-windows-msvc" - the toolchain or the target? I guess you've installed the former, but using the latter.

Comment: How did you install `stable-i686-pc-windows-msvc`?

Comment: @Cerberus This seem to be the cause... I was unaware of the difference between toolchain and target. Make it an answer so I can award you the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a misunderstanding on what is *toolchain* and what is *target*.

The code is always being built for some *target triple* - it's usually fully defined by the system in question (Windows systems are an exception, since they have two kinds of target triples - `*-msvc` and `*-gnu`, depending on the C compiler and linker).

When you install the toolchain, using the

```
rustup toolchain install toolchain-name
```

its name is defined as *compiler_version*-*target_triple*, e.g. `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`. The target triple here is the one which was used to build the compiler, i.e. it is defined by the *host* system - the one which runs the compilation process; therefore, almost always all the installed toolchains will differ only in `version` part - e.g., if you need some code to use the nightly-only features, you'll install `nigtly-*triple*` alongside the `stable-*triple*`.

When you add the target, using the

```
rustup target add target-name
```

its name is just the target triple, without reference to the compiler version. In this case, the triple is what is used by the compiler, building *your own code*, and for the prebuilt standard library; and that's what you need to use when you're using the compiler for cross-compilation, including compilation to another processor architecture (32-bit vs 64-bit). The compiler itself will still be build for your host, but it will emit artifacts for another system.